# Client side validation on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to prevent multiple clicks on submit button.
I manage to do it by freezing the screen when clicking the submit button.
Only problem is with client side validation.
When a required field is empty, the screen is frozen and i can't do anything else in this page.
I am trying to check validation of the form, but it doesn't look like it's working.
I'm getting that form is valid all the time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AddBtn').click(function () {
        if ($("form").valid()) {
            $('body').append('<div id="over" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');

        } else {
            window.alert('NOT VALID');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is one of the fields with validation:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label asp-for="Orders.CustZipCode">Zip Code</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <input asp-for="Orders.CustZipCode" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Orders.CustZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this may not be exactly what you are looking for but i tend to replace the form element with a spinner upon successful submit. having said this, i am using Ajax.BeginForm for ajax calls and this seems to work as a pretty straight-forward solution. this a) removes the form from view so user can no longer mess with it once he/she submitted the form and b) spinner gives them a feeling the app busy doing something meaninful working on the data they submitted.

i suppose i have a quesiton - where do you take a user upon successful submission - do you take them to the new view or the form remains on the screen?

Comment: Hi Yan,
upon success there will be a sweet alert, when pressing the button in the swal message, it redirect back to orders screen

Comment: what are you using for client-side validation? i assume jquery validation plugin. i suppose we need to look into why validator believes the form is valid - have you seen this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881726/jquery-validate-always-returning-true